# Is it possible to define fields at the schema level that are calculated from another field using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to define fields at the schema level that are based off of another field using mongoose schemas?

For example, say I have this very simple schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  username_lower: {
    type: String,
    // calculated: this.username.toLowerCase()
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email_lower: { // for case-insensitive email indexing/lookup
    type: String,
    // calculated: this.email.toLowerCase()
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password_acceptable: {
    type: Array,
    // calculated: [
    //    this.password.toLowerCase(),
    //    this.password.toUpperCase()
    //    this.password.removeWhiteSpace(), // just an example
    //  ]
  }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Is there something similar to the dummy "calculated" fields (that I've commented out) that would allow automatic field creation when the new document is saved? This would be very convenient and would reduce the clutter from having to manually define these fields on my back-end routes.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by Pre middleware function, for more [details](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(){
   this.username_lower = this.username.toLowerCase();
   this.email_lower = this.email.toLowerCase();
   // and so on ...
   next();
});
```

Comment: Okay I will try that; looks promising. Thank you! @Nemer

Comment: Before exporting, I've now added a pre save function to the schema, in which case I don't need to call next(). I believe it will work for my application, except I need to move my password hashing into the pre save function now so that each acceptable password is the hashed version and the actual password gets overwritten with the hash during this function as well. I will test out, but I think this is an acceptable answer to my question. Thanks again.